# Программа\плагин для анализа планов запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите программу с помощью которой можно удобно анализировать планы.
Например, где с легкостью можно увидеть разницу в планах между двумя похожими запросами, какие узлы изменилиcь/добавились/удалились, какая-нибудь общая статистика по числу сканов и т п.

В SQLMS есть стандартный обозреватель планов, но он не сильно удобный.

Comment: [Не оно?](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-compare-query-execution-plans-in-sql-server-2016/)

Comment: посмотрите еще sql plan explorer
https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer

Comment: плюсую за SentryOne Plan Explorer, очень удобно для получения расширенной информации и сравнения планов.

Comment: @mickey.1cx, а там можно сравнить 2 плана? Какие конкретно узлы поменялись?